# Bilinear form dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I saw that the dimension of a Bilinear form is:
$$ \dim B(V,W) = \dim V \cdot \dim W $$

where a bilinear form means (in my course):
$$ B : V\times W \rightarrow F $$
I don't really understand why, and I can't find a proper explanation anywhere.

Comment: It will help to say exactly what you mean by a bilinear form.  There are several formalisms here: in one, it is a kind of function, not a kind of vector space, so it doesn't have a dimension.  In other, it is an element of a certain tensor space, so it does.

Comment: Ok, i will edit my question... Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean the *space* of bilinear forms, i.e. maps $V\times W\to k$ that are linear in both $V$ and $W$. Then note that this space is essentially the space of linear maps $V\to W^*$ where $W^*$ is the dual space of $W$.

Comment: @Tomer: Does a map between vector spaces have a "dimension"?  What does that mean?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I don't really understand what do you mean by "map"... we didn't call it like that in my course...

Comment: @Tomer: "map" = "function": your $B$ is a map.  What is the dimension of a linear function between vector spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and $(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ a basis of $V$ and $W$ respectively and let

$$\Phi\colon B(V,W)\rightarrow \mathcal M_{nm}(\Bbb R), \varphi\mapsto \left(\varphi(e_i,f_j)\right)_{ij}$$
so we can see that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism of linear vector spaces so
$$\dim B(V,W)=\dim \mathcal M_{nm}(\Bbb R)=nm=\dim V\times \dim W$$